# How can I access an LDAP-Server to autocomplete address headers in message-mode/GNUS

Tags: gnus

I'm using GNUS to access a bunch of IMAP servers. When composing new messages it would be nice to have access to the companies ldap server for autocompletion on address headers TO/CC/BCC. Is this possible, and if, how?

Comment: [Here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16322) are some patches that try to simplify EUDC configuration.

Comment: @legoscia this looks great; time to compile master again already? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Update per comments]

**Disclaimer: I'm not using EUDC or LDAP at this time, thus I have no current setup of it.**

I've had success with [EUDC](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EUDC) in the past, it wasn't complicated to setup with autocompletion.

First, I copied exactly the configuration described in the `EUDC` wiki page. 
The only thing that I recall being an issue was making sure that I had the right LDAP `base`, `address` and `binddn` fields setup.

I ended up setting credentials via `M-x customize-group` as I far as I know.

I then replaced all the related server fields with my configuration (Copying wiki stuff here, just for inline reference...).

```
(require 'ldap)
(require 'eudc)

(setq eudc-default-return-attributes nil
      eudc-strict-return-matches nil)

(setq ldap-ldapsearch-args (quote ("-tt" "-LLL" "-x")))
(setq eudc-inline-query-format '((name)
                                 (firstname)
                                 (firstname name)
                                 (email)
                                 ))

(setq ldap-host-parameters-alist
      (quote (("your_server" base "ou=addressbook,dc=your_dc_here,dc=fr"
               binddn "cn=admin,dc=your_dc_here,dc=fr"
               passwd "your_password"))))

(eudc-set-server "your_server" 'ldap t)
(setq eudc-server-hotlist '(("your_server" . ldap)))
(setq eudc-inline-expansion-servers 'hotlist)

(defun enz-eudc-expand-inline()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (insert "*")
  (unless (condition-case nil
              (eudc-expand-inline)
            (error nil))
    (backward-delete-char-untabify 1))
  )

;; Adds some hooks

(eval-after-load "message"
  '(define-key message-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'enz-eudc-expand-inline))
(eval-after-load "sendmail"
  '(define-key mail-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'enz-eudc-expand-inline))
(eval-after-load "post"
  '(define-key post-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'enz-eudc-expand-inline))
```

Comment: Please ellaborate on how you set it up/what you have as your configuration.  Link only answers are not recommended because the link can change in the future.

Comment: The linked config does not work for me (with the relevant parts filled in with correct values); the paramters used directly with ldapsearch at the commandline gets results, emacs apparently does not even try something; is there proper documentation somewhere?

Comment: I renounce anything I said -- it works now; somewhere in my attempts to get it working I added "scope 'subtree" according to the docs for other client-systems -- that got in the way; all I had to add was "-ZZ" to the ldap-ldapsearch-args for TLS.